# Angular Rxjs. don't close the subscription after reaching the error, but log the error in Angular's error handler

Tags: angular, rxjs, custom-error-handling

community.
I have one problem. I need to log an error in Angular's error handler without closing the stream subscription when an error occurs.

I have the following data stream:

```
/**DATA Provider Service*/
 getData(settings): Observable<any> {
  return HttpClientGET$(settings).pipe(
/***/
   map(response => transformMethod(response)),
/***/
   tap(convertedData => sendData(convertedData))
 );
}

sendData(data: any): void {
  this.replaySubject.next(data);
}

getConvertedData(): Observable<any> {
  this.replaySubject.asObservable();
}
```

```
 /**Parent Component*/

ngOnInit(): void {
 this.changePositionStream$.pipe(
  switchMap((settings) => this.dataService.getData(settings))
).subscribe();
}
```

```
/**Child - Data Component*/

ngONInit(): void {
  this.service.getConvertedData().subscribe();
}
```

Issue - an error can be caught in the Angular error handler when the error stream doesn't interrupt or use the `throwError()`. But when an error is thrown the subscription is closing.

How do I log an error without closing the data subscription?

Comment: try with ngdestroy and inside ngdestroy use unsuscribe

Comment: from which class do you want to catch the error?

Comment: @IlCorsaroNero - I'm sorry, but I don't need to unsubscribe - I need to save the thread and send the error to the logger

Comment: @ChrisDanna - I think in the Child component.

Answer (score 1):

You can use RxJS materialize to handle errors and discard them:

```
export const catchAndDefaultTo = <T, K>(defaultValue?: K): MonoTypeOperatorFunction<T | K> => pipe(
  materialize(),
  map(n => n.kind !== 'C'
    ? new Notification('N', n.value || defaultValue)
    : n
  ),
  dematerialize(),
)
```

Error notification does not have a value so `n.value` will not be set here and it will create a next notification instead with whatever is set as `defaultValue`. Error notification is now "discarded" and a next notification is send instead thus it will not close the stream.

I am not sure what part of your stream you want to handle so I assume somewhere here:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.changePositionStream$.pipe(
    switchMap((settings) => this.dataService.getData(settings)),
    catchAndDefaultTo(undefined)
  ).subscribe();
}
```

I am not 100% sure what materialize does but how I see it let's you manipulate every notification (next, error and complete) that goes through your stream.

Comment: thank you for the explanation - I absolutely forget about "materialize" and Notification.

Comment: but isn't that similar to the behavior of the `onErrorResumeNext` operator?

Answer (score 1):

In the general case what you're asking isn't possible.

As per the [Observable contract](https://reactivex.io/documentation/contract.html), once an observable has emitted an `error` or `complete`, then that observable is done and may never emit anything else (it's free to release any resources, etc). An observable will never `error` twice, `complete` twice, or both `error` **and** `complete`. Once is all it gets.

RxJS does come with a set of tools to manage errors and re-try/re-subscribe to source observables etc. We can't know from what you've written here, what would work for you, but there are many questions/answers already about how to do manage RxJS errors.

Answer (score 1):

As Mrk Sef said, you can't get more than one error. You can catch the error instead:

```
    throwError(() => 'error')
      .pipe(catchError(err => {
        // handle error
        console.log(err);
        return of(err);
      }))
      .subscribe(res => {
        if (res != 'error') {
          // handle success
          console.log('This happen on on success')
        }
      });
```